# Github actions runner environment doesn't build for arm images

Tags: docker, github-actions

I get this error on my github build:

> The requested image's platform (linux/arm/v7) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested

The runner environment I'm using is the ubuntu:latest and my container uses arm32v7/node base image.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/node AS appbuild
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY src/ ./src
RUN npm install

FROM appbuild as release
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

And here's my deployment to github yaml:

```
jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

The jobs are ran inside a ubuntu runner environment. I suspect the arm version of the node image I'm using is unable to run in that environment, is that correct?

Edit:

```
  - name: Build controller image
    if: steps.changed-files-plantcontroller.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
    run: >
      docker build -t ${{ env.image_name_controller }} ${{ env.context }}
    env:
      context: ./controller
```

Comment: You are correct. If you want to build armv7 on arm64, you can use buildx. Check out [this action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/master/docs/advanced/multi-platform.md). In this case, you would use `platform: linux/arm/v7`.

Comment: You can simplify your Dockerfile some if you like as well, I tried to briefly mention that in an answer but did something similar [here](https://github.com/csci104/docker/blob/a2fe3b890228d9f47b4bb77715bfb67b4dda97e9/.github/workflows/build-on-pr.yml) to build 2 different architectures with a somewhat generic [Dockerfile](https://github.com/csci104/docker/blob/a2fe3b890228d9f47b4bb77715bfb67b4dda97e9/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 8):

You are correct. Docker on your arm64 build environment cannot build the arm32v7 image without Docker Buildx. You can solve this by using the [buildx Github Action](https://github.com/docker/setup-buildx-action) and [qemu action](https://github.com/docker/setup-qemu-action), that prepares your environment to build multi-arch images.

Buildx is Docker's technology to build images for a target architecture not matching the host's (in this case the host arch is `arm64`). You can read about how this works [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/).

[QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) is an emulator used by Docker buildx. It's a dependency I learned the hard way was needed when [writing a multi-arch workflow](https://github.com/csci104/docker/blob/main/.github/workflows/publish-image.yml).

For more reference, check out this doc: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/master/docs/advanced/multi-platform.md

You should be able to build your image with a workflow with something like this:

```yaml
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'master'

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      -
        name: Set up QEMU dependency
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - name: Build controller image
        if: steps.changed-files-plantcontroller.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: ${{ env.context }}
          tags: ${{ env.image_name_controller }}
          platforms: linux/arm/v7
          push: true
        env:
          context: ./controller
```

**NOTE**: Updated the last build command with how you have your `Build controller image` step written. It just translates the Docker command to how the Docker build-push-action builds.

An alternative command you could use in place of the `build-push-action@v2`:

```
docker buildx build -t ${{ env.image_name_controller }} --platform linux/arm/v7 --push ${{ env.context }}
```

The command assumes you want to push to a GitHub repo with the tag.

---

Unrelated, but there's an opportunity to simplify your Dockerfile.

When you're using buildx, Docker can handle pulling the right arm32v7 version of the image when the image you're pulling has multiple versions. Check out the [node image tags](https://hub.docker.com/_/node?tab=tags) and you'll see `linux/arm/v7` listed as one of the OS/Arch tags. What this means is you could simplify your `FROM arm32v7/node AS appbuild` line to `FROM node AS appbuild` if you think you want to build for a different architecture sometime.

For example:

- [Github workflow](https://github.com/csci104/docker/blob/a2fe3b890228d9f47b4bb77715bfb67b4dda97e9/.github/workflows/build-on-pr.yml) that builds for `amd64` and `arm64`
- [Dockerfile](https://github.com/csci104/docker/blob/a2fe3b890228d9f47b4bb77715bfb67b4dda97e9/Dockerfile) that pulls relevant `amd64` or `arm64` image depending on TARGETPLATFORM

Comment: Thank you for this. And where to I put my run command? Right after the Build image for platform arm v7 action?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to have any arbitrary run command after the steps included in the snippet. Just add a separate step. These docs might also be helpful: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun

Comment: For example, I have this run action: 

`      - name: Build controller image
        if: steps.changed-files-controller.outputs.any_changed == 'true'
        run: >
          docker build -t ${{ env.image_name_controller }} ${{ env.context }}
        env:
          context: ./controller` And I don't know where to place it, should it be after the Build Image for platform arm v7?

Comment: I edited my question to reflect my comment

Comment: @Johnnyboy Ah I see. I edited the workflow to translate that build command to use the docker/build-push-action parameters for context and tag.

Comment: I like the buildx build command, thank you. I'll try it out right now

Comment: @Johnnyboy Did that command (or something like it) end up working or were there issues?

Comment: Still working on it @tentative. I was also wondering what does the --push ${{ env.context }} do? Is the push flag needed? Because when github executes my actions I get that the image doesn't exist, but exists

Comment: Maybe this will fix the error? docker buildx build -t ${{ env.image_name_controller }} ${{ env.context }} --platform linux/arm/v7

Comment: I still get: Error response from daemon: No such image: ghcr.io/website/controller:latest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240061/discussion-between-tentative-and-johnny-boy).

Answer (score 3):

That should change starting Q1 2024:

> ### [Accelerate your CI/CD with Arm-based hosted runners in GitHub Actions](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-10-30-accelerate-your-ci-cd-with-arm-based-hosted-runners-in-github-actions) (Oct. 2023)
>
> Arm-based hosted runners are coming to GitHub Actions!
>
> By leveraging the power and efficiency of the Arm® architecture, GitHub is offering a new solution that will accelerate software development in GitHub.
> These new capabilities empower GitHub users to shift-left software development on the Arm architecture across the embedded edge, IoT and cloud infrastructure while providing significant power, performance and sustainability improvements to all users.
> Developers can now take advantage of Arm hardware hosted by GitHub to build and deploy their release assets anywhere Arm’s architecture is used.
>
> Seamlessly integrated into GitHub Actions, these runners are powered by Arm-based Ampere® Altra® processors.
> Preloaded with a base image that contains a foundational set of development tools to build upon, these runners are extremely versatile and can handle any embedded software project from key markets such as automotive, IoT and industrial.
> The benefits do not stop at the embedded edge, as non-embedded, cloud native and everything in between will benefit by reducing their carbon footprint and getting more done within existing budgets.
>
> These runners will be entering private beta in January 2024.
>
> “With Arm-based GitHub-hosted runners, software developers can move faster while taking full advantage of the efficient Arm architecture, from cloud to edge,” said Bhumik Patel, director of software ecosystem development, Infrastructure Line of Business, Arm.
> “Our partnership with GitHub allows developers to optimize their Arm-based software development workflows and leverage GitHub’s ubiquitous deployment capability to more efficiently deliver code wherever they deploy – all while reducing costs and time to market.”
>
> **Interested?**

Click [here](https://resources.github.com/devops/accelerate-your-cicd-with-arm-and-gpu-runners-in-github-actions/) to join the waitlist for the private beta.

In the meantime, QEMU + buildx remains a viable alternative.

Comment: Glad to hear that