# How do I build an arm image using github docker/build-push-action

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions

I have a github workflow that I want to use to build a multi-arch image. Currently, I have written it to create both the x86_64 and arm64 images separately using docker build-push-action and the run a script to bundle this into a multi-arch manifest.

i.e.

```
.github/workflows

name: Build and Push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:

  build-and-push:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set date
      id: date
      run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date +'%m-%d-%Y')"
    - name: Authenticate
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        registry: quay.io
        username: ${{ secrets.QUAY_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.QUAY_PASSWORD }}
    - name: Build and Push x86 image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        file: ./images/Containerfile
        push: true
        tags: |
          quay.io/user/tools:${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}-x86_64
    - name: Build and Push ARM64 image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        file: ./images/Containerfile
        push: true
        platforms: linux/arm64
        tags: |
          quay.io/user/tools:${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}-aarch64
    - name: Create and Push Multi-Architecture Manifest
      run: |
        sudo podman manifest create tools-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}-list
        sudo podman manifest add tools-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}-list quay.io/user/tools:${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}-x86_64
        sudo podman manifest add tools-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}-list quay.io/user/tools:${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}-aarch64
        sudo podman manifest push tools-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}-list quay.io/user/tools:${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
        sudo podman manifest push tools-${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}-list quay.io/user/tools:latest
```

For testing, all my containerfile does is install a couple simple packages with yum and run /bin/bash

```
FROM quay.io/centos/centos:stream9

RUN INSTALL_PKGS="vim wget" && yum install -y ${INSTALL_PKGS}

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The x86_64 job runs fine, however the arm64 job will fail. The error message seems to suggest it is being build on the wrong architecture.

```
#4 [2/2] RUN INSTALL_PKGS="vim wget" && yum install -y ${INSTALL_PKGS}
#4 0.203 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
#4 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c INSTALL_PKGS=\"vim wget\" && yum install -y ${INSTALL_PKGS}" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [2/2] RUN INSTALL_PKGS="vim wget" && yum install -y ${INSTALL_PKGS}:
0.203 exec /bin/sh: exec format error
------
./images/Containerfile:3
--------------------
   1 |     FROM quay.io/centos/centos:stream9
   2 |     
   3 | >>> RUN INSTALL_PKGS="vim wget" && yum install -y ${INSTALL_PKGS}
   4 |     
   5 |     CMD ["/bin/bash"]
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c INSTALL_PKGS=\"vim wget\" && yum install -y ${INSTALL_PKGS}" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c INSTALL_PKGS=\"vim wget\" && yum install -y ${INSTALL_PKGS}" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

How do I properly build an arm64 image with github actions in this way?

Comment: There is an architecture mismatch there - I believe that your runner is amd64, but the container you are pulling in that step is arm64. Hence the "exec format error". Since `buildx` supports multi-arch builds, wouldn't simply doing a `platforms: linux/amd64, linux/arm64` on the `build-push-action` work for you?

Comment: Updating platforms: to include both these images results in this error: ERROR: Multiple platforms feature is currently not supported for docker driver. Please switch to a different driver (eg. "docker buildx create --use")
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: Multiple platforms feature is currently not supported for docker driver. Please switch to a different driver (eg. "docker buildx create --use")

Comment: Switching the using docker buildx build does seem to solve the issue
      run: |
        docker buildx build \
          --file ./images/Containerfile \
          --platform linux/arm64 \

Comment: Note: [Arm-based hosted runners are coming to GitHub Actions in Q1 2024](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77429129/6309). A private beta is available now (Q4 2023)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I was able to achieve what I wanted using docker buildx as suggested in the comments. However, still curious why my initial approach didn't work and if there is a more proper "github workflow" way to go about this.

```
name: Build and Push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-push:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      run: |
        docker buildx create --use
    - name: Set date
      id: date
      run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date +'%m-%d-%Y')"
    - name: Authenticate
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        registry: quay.io
        username: ${{ secrets.QUAY_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.QUAY_PASSWORD }}
    - name: Build and Push image
      run: |
        docker buildx build \
          --file ./images/Containerfile \
          --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64\
          --tag quay.io/user/tools:${{ steps.date.outputs.date }} \
          --push .
```

Comment: I do believe this is the proper "github workflow" way. With one small note - there is actually a dedicated [setup-buildx-action](https://github.com/docker/setup-buildx-action) you can use. See also [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/multi-platform/)